# XClass in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

Now I am using TYPO3 6.2beta5 version and in that website I need to include an XClass for the extension sr_feuser_register. Its a "PI_Base" extension and I tried the following methods to include XClass, but not working anymore;

> -> localconf.php
>
> $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['tx_srfeuserregister_display']
>   = array( 'className' => 'ux_tx_srfeuserregister_display');
>
> -> ext_autoload.php
>
> $extensionPath =
>   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('extname');
>
> return array(     'ux_tx_srfeuserregister_display' =>
>   $extensionPath.'class.ux_tx_srfeuserregister_display.php',    );

Does anybody knows the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct for non namespaced classes.
The reasons why your code does not work can be as follows:

1) **The xclass hasn't been autoloaded** - Because you didn't clear "All caches" yet. The autoloader caches all paths! Additionaly autoloading breaks partially if there is an error in any of the ext_autoload.php files loaded (all extensions). You won't notice that in the frontend because no exception and no PHP error will be thrown.

2) The instance of the original class is beeing instantiated without the use of GeneralUtility::makeInstance() but directly (new tx_srfeuserregister_display)

3) The class is in fact extended but the method you want to overload is beeing used in a static way (class::method())

4) Sometimes the class key inside the Objects array is different from what you might expect (here $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['**tx_srfeuserregister_display**']). When I am desperate to find a reason why an XCLASS does not work, I try to devlog the classnames resolved by GeneralUtility::getImplementationForClass().

Hope some of the above helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you suggest me a method to implement this?. I want to extend "class.tx_srfeuserregister_display.php" file with my own file "class.ux_tx_srfeuserregister_display.php" and class "ux_tx_srfeuserregister_display".

Comment: I already told you that the way you try to do it is correct. Assumed your extension, where the XCLASS is implemented, is properly installed and all TYPO3 caches have been cleared, there is no evident reason why your XCLASS couldn't get registered. If it isn't, then you have a problem to debug and I gave you hints where to start.

Comment: In TYPO3 7.6.14 it is not possible to call the `protected static function getImplementationForClass($className)` by `GeneralUtility::getImplementationForClass()` . It gives a **Fatal error: Call to protected method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getImplementationForClass()**

Answer (score 0):

This is happened due to cache. My code was correct and I clear all the typo3temp cache and it is working now.

Comment: Didn't I mention TYPO3 caches twice? Bullet 1) and one comment. :-)
So please accept my answer since I got the point exactly, that your implementation was correct and cache might be the first reason.

Thank you.

Comment: I've seen your question on TYPO3 forum today again. http://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/202348/. Nothing really different there, from what I have told you in my answer. You have accepted the answer there, so do it here as well please ;-)